# How to remove this exception while making jdbc example ?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am creating a simple example of jdbc .I am getting this error .I run my sql server on my mac machine .can you please tell me how to make connection with my sql and remove this error .I already include connector jar file .

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1129)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:358)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at HelloWorldExample.main(HelloWorldExample.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: local
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:877)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1230)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1181)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1111)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1047)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:248)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:308)
    ... 15 more
```

Here is my code ..I am using mac

```
import java.sql.*;
/**
* HelloWorldExample : JDBC Tutorial that creates a simple database, stores in a single row
* and retrieves the data to then be displayed on standard out. The database is cleaned up 
* to reduce clutter for this example.
* Author: Kevin Hooks
* Date: April 18th, 2012
**/
public class HelloWorldExample {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        // Note that you can use TCP/IP by using this URL
        // "jdbc:raima:rdm://localhost"
        // The rdmsqlserver must be running to use TCP/IP
        Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://local");
        try {

            Statement Stmt =  Conn.createStatement();
            try {
                try { //Since the database is created here, it cannot be created twice
                    Stmt.execute("DROP DATABASE hello_db");
                } catch (SQLException exception) {} 

                Stmt.execute("CREATE DATABASE hello_Db");
                Stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE hello_table (f00 char(31))");
                Conn.commit();

                PreparedStatement PrepStmt = Conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO hello_table (f00) VALUES (?)");
                try { //Sets parameter value to a string         
                    PrepStmt.setString(1, "Hello World!");
                    PrepStmt.execute();
                    Conn.commit();

                    ResultSet RS = Stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM hello_table");
                    try {

                        while(RS.next() != false) {
                            System.out.println(RS.getString(1));
                        }
                    } finally {
                        RS.close();
                    }
                } finally { //Cleans up by dropping database in this case
                    Stmt.execute("DROP DATABASE hello_db");
                    PrepStmt.close();
                }
            } finally {
                Stmt.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + exception.toString());

        }finally {
             Conn.close();           
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The hostname of the loopback address is `localhost`, not `local`.

Answer (score 1):

you have declared wrong connection string. please modified it according to below rule

```
Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>
> at HelloWorldExample.main(HelloWorldExample.java:17)

Line 17:

```
Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://local");
```

Your program can not establish a connection to the database, be sure that you have your connection URL correct.

`local`, should be replaced by `localhost`, or `127.0.0.1`

You should also note, that you never actually select a database to use.

Answer (score 0):

your URL should be localhost then add the database name

have a look at this

```
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.SQLException;

  public class JDBCExample {

  public static void main(String[] argv) {

    System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongcom","root", "password");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {


    System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
  }
}
```